# Error: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, pom.xml

I'm trying to run my application with SpringBoot, however I'm getting this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Here are my codes for pom.xml and application properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.itb.projeto</groupId>
    <artifactId>padaria3x</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>padaria3x</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://TCC_InteractiveLibrary.mssql.somee.com;databaseName=TCC_InteractiveLibrary
spring.datasource.username=JoãoFerreira_SQLLogin_1
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2016Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=1MB
```

I've also realised that in pom.xml, the first parent class is labelled as an error, I don't really know why, but just commenting in case this is somehow helpful

[Parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7H4y.png)

I seriously can't identify the problem and don't even know what to try at this point, since everything looks like it's checking out.